# Aurelia-Auth Login issue. Not sending authentication payload

Tags: authentication, aurelia, aurelia-auth

I'm trying to use aurelia-auth (ver 3.0.5) for authentication in my app.
I'm trying to use the 'local strategy' and have put up a dummy authentication service.
I'm using the following code to call the login method and tried both with email/password call or the object one with the same result, I get no payload of a username and password sent to the server when checking network traffic in Chrome debugger. It does go to the correct url and my service is getting called, but without any information to authenticate.

```
login() {
  let cred = { user: this.email, password: this.password };
  // return this.auth.login(this.email, this.password)
  return this.auth.login(cred) 
  .then(response=>{
    console.log('success logged ' + response);
  })
  .catch(err=>{
    err.json().then(function(e) {
      console.log('login failure : ' + e.message);
    });
  });
}
```

This is my config for the Aurelia-auth component:

```
var config = {  
 signupUrl: 'users',  
 loginUrl: '/api/auth/login',  
 tokenName: 'id_token',  
 loginRedirect: '#/'
};
```

Comment: Are you using a dev environment and run aurelia on a different domain as the auth server?

Comment: @MarcScheib. I'm running a dev maching, but the auth service is hosted in the same app, and on the same domain! The request is arriving to the server ok, but there is no username or password sent from the client.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide access to the demo? Or can you set up a small repo reproducing this issue? You can also try to authenticate directly using copying this method (https://github.com/paulvanbladel/aurelia-auth/blob/master/src/auth-service.js#L69) in your code and see whats happening then.

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure that you are sending the data to the same exact domain? When inspecting dev tools, what type of http verb do you see for the request? POST or OPTIONS?